# How to use a node.js library in html?

Tags: node.js, npm

I install fancybox dependency via :

```
npm install fancybox
```

I'm attempting to use the fancybox css within a html page :

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe"
```

I cannot `require` the fancybox library within the html page ?

Prior to using node I would just import the library directly on the page:

```
   <script src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css"></link>
```

But how to use the node library on html page ?

Update :

To achieve this I just copied the node_modules directory to the public folder. Then exposed the library with :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is to use a build tool such as webpack. You use npm to install your libraries into the `node_modules/` subdirectory, require them within your javascript files and use webpack to produce a single bundle .js file that contains everything.

I'd start here: http://webpack.github.io/docs/what-is-webpack.html

Comment: I just copied the modules dir to the public folder.